# wp7 refresh page from App.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, app.xaml

i'v added some button to my applicationBar, in which a refresh also exist & i attached an event handler `onClick` to it, but i'v put this applicationBar in App.xaml &  i am including it in my all pages, so now its getting exact uri from which page the refresh button has been clicked (`ReloadUri`) with this code--->

```
private void ReloadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ReloadUri = (((App)Application.Current).RootFrame.Content as PhoneApplicationPage).NavigationService.CurrentSource;
            (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(ReloadUri);
        }
```

but in second line of code above the page not navigating (**navigation not working**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved !
fixed the issue using `no-cache parameter`--->

```
(Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(new Uri(ReloadUri +"?no-cache="+Guid.NewGuid(), UriKind.Relative));
```